# Template based Indexing/Extraction with Apache Nutch & Solr

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

I am new to Apache Nutch/Solr family of products. I have setup basic Nutch (1.6) with Solr (4.3) and have successfully crawled a site and Solr has indexed my crawled data as well.

Now my question is if I crawl a web blog like where user can give their comments (e.g http://blogs.alliedtechnique.com/2009/04/16/setting-global-environment-variables-in-centos/), how can I make sure Nutch consider user's comments and main blog as separate document, So when I search for keyword , it returns me main blog and comments as separate results and later I could use that data for sentiment analysis as well.

I would greatly appreciate any help here.

Thanks.
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the xpath filter plugin to segregate crawled content into two different fields.
http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/

Content in class="post" would go to field A, content in class="commentlist" would go to field B.

In your search page logic, you query Solr on field A so your search results are only from your blog post, not the comments.

Comments data is still saved against the document, but not searchable.